# Why do I hear noise out of my headphones when rubbing its male connector to a metal container's wall filled with water?

Tags: electrostatics, noise

When I rub the male jack of my heaphone cable to the inner walls of any metal container filled with water, I can hear crackling noises. I don't know how could this little bit of rubbing generate such a good amount of current to actually make those noises come out of a passive headphone.

I have also recorded a little clip of it ([link here](https://youtu.be/17UhgHq9k3U)).

And when I try to do the same thing with a glass container, it doesn't happen. So surely there is some kind of electrostatic phenomenon involved, but I just don't get the math of it.

Comment: You have possibly made a cell (two metal electrodes with an electrolyte in between) which generated an emf and so produces a current though you headphones. Which metal was the container made of?

Comment: @Farcher Steel and iron show the same effect.

Comment: The container is probably reasonably well earthed, while the headphones / you are not, so what you're hearing is noise resulting from that.  With high-impedance headphones you can get clicks & crackles quite easily by touching anything conductive with the end of the jack.

Comment: The container wasn't well earthed and my headphones don't have a very high impedance as well,  may be impedance is the issue but the earthing is a no. While recording the whole setup was on a 4cm thick plastic insulating sheet.